# error C2664: StartAt: невозможно преобразовать параметр 1 из "P **" в "const P **"

Tags: c++

Почему возникает эта ошибка? Почему так нельзя делать?

```
class P {
    int X;
    int Y;
};

void StartAt(P const **p) {
    // Определить точку начала
}

void EndAt(P const **p) {
    // Определить точку конца
}

void main() {
    P *p;

    StartAt(&p);
    EndAt(&p);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так нельзя делать, потому что типы `P*` и `P const*` - это разные типы. И Вы пытаетесь неявно привести указатель на один тип к указателю на другой тип. И эти два типа не связаны отношением наследования. И тип указателя, к которому пытаются привести не является `void*`.

В общем, основная причина в том, что `P*` и `P const*` - это разные типы, которые не имеют неявного способа приведения друг к другу.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка, видимо, в момент выполнения: указатель есть, но он указывает в непонятную и, скорее всего, неподвластную вашему процессу память.

Кроме того, обычно пишут `const P **` - нельзя менять данные по указателю.